# Make a large image fit into a imageview of small size

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am trying to make a large image fit into an `UIImageView` of small size. How can I reduce the size of the image or scale it appropriately so that the full image fits into the `UIImageView`?

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Answer (score 0):

try to use different modes like `scale to fill` ,  `aspect fit` , aspect fill` etc.

i think accorging to your requirement `scale to fill` is good.

`aspect fit` will keep the original shape your image and fit accorging to aspect ratio so it will possible that some portion of your imageview remains blank or not cover by image.

Scale to fit try to scale image according to imageview. this is by default mode.

aspect fill will fill whole imageview with aspect ratio.

so choose whatever is best for you. you can easily change mode from storyboard from attribute inspector.

hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the desired frame of your imageView and set the content mode of the image View. For example :

```
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
//OR 
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
//OR
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
```

Use whichever works for you.

By looking at the JSON I'm updating the answer:

As I had suspected, its a URL which you are getting in JSON. So do the following:

1. Parse the JSON and get the URL from the JSON.(videothumbnail key value)
2. The URL contains back slashes as escape charecters(http://content.m-tutor.com/images/20150916113347_5-cont.png) remove them to get the URL as this http://content.m-tutor.com/images/20150916113347_5-cont.png
3. Download the image Using below code :

   ```
   func startDownloadImageWithURL(urlInString: String?){

   let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession();

   if let urlInString = urlInString{
       let urlToDownload = NSURL(string: urlInString)
       session.dataTaskWithURL(urlToDownload!, completionHandler: {(data : NSData?,response : NSURLResponse?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
               if let error = error {
                   print("Error while downloading \(error.localizedDescription)")
               }
               else{
                   //Assuming the yourImageView is already initialized with position
                   //yourImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
               }
           })
       }).resume()
   }
   }
   ```

I have given just an example on how to download image(get the data), create the image using data downloaded and the set it to imageView, you can update it according to your need.
 Hope it helps :]

Comment: thanks a lot for responding but its not working for me

Comment: Ok, What exactly is happening when you are trying to set the image?  Can you give more details or share a screen shot?

Comment: I am getting the image via JSON, and displaying the image on UIImageview. I have tried changing the modes of UIImageview, but no change is observed.

Comment: Ok, you are getting data of the image form JSON or the url for the image?

Comment: If you are getting the url of the image then you have to download the image using the URL and set the imageView Image using the data of the image you have downloaded by using : imageView.image = UIImage(data:<downloaded_data>)

Comment: I am getting the image from the JSON, sorry for delayed response

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide the JSON response. So that I get some more clarity.

Comment: @Chandhan005 its official can't share in public. Can I ping via mail, if yes share your ID

Comment: Don't share the entire JSON, I just want to know in what form you are getting the image. Anyways if you can't share here send it to chandan.05rey009@gmail.com(If mailing send the entire JSON)

Answer (score 0):

set the mode of the imageView to `Aspect Fit`

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, but I don't have any change in my view

Answer (score 0):

Set the this property for your image view

```
imageView.contentMode  = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```